# Class 'Dompdf\Dompdf' not found in Production Server

Tags: codeigniter, production-environment, dompdf

There is no issues encountered on local developement. Once got live/production, the problem came out with class not found errors.

**System Backbone and Library**

- Dompdf `0.7.x@beta` for both `local and production`
- Codeigniter 3.0

**Local development**

- Windows 8.1
- PHP 5.6.3

**Production Environment**

- Ubuntu 14.0 LTS
- PHP 7

As Dompdf prior to version 7 and above, i'm using namespace in my controller. Here is the step of installations.

1. Installing `dompdf` using composer
2. Upon successful `Vendor` directory was created at the root of project
3. I'm auto loaded composer's autoload.php file by set the path inside `application/config/config.php` eg : `$config['composer_autoload'] = './vendor/autoload.php';`
4. Then i call the dompdf namespace at my controller like so : `use Dompdf\Dompdf;`
5. And last, at one of my class's method, i'm instantiated the class with : `new DOMPDF();`, also try with `new \DOMPDF();` and `new Dompdf();` but all of these failed.

**Sample code**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

class App extends CI_Controller {
  public function testPdf() {
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    //------------ All failed
    // $dompdf = new \DOMPDF();
    // $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    // $dompdf = new \Dompdf();
    // $dompdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf\Dompdf();
  }
.........
.........
```

Anyone encountered this?

Comment: 0.7.0 is now out of beta. You might try without the beta tag in your composer config.

Comment: @BrianS : sorry for the late reply. Seems like the problem because the version issues. I just tried installing another version and the errors gone out seamlessly.